# Disable remote file cleanup in recentf?

Tags: tramp, recentf

When using recentf with tramp, recentf would clean up its file list including all remote files, which takes a lot of time when the Internet is bad. How can I ask recentf to not cleanup remote files, without disabling recent file list auto cleanup for local files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`M-x customize-option RET recentf-keep RET`, and be sure to read its description.

You can use any arbitrary or conditional expression. And that includes `file-remote-p`.

Comment: sort of old, but maybe you mean't `file-remote-p` ?

Comment: @joefromct: Yes; updated. Thx.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue: remote files are removed from the recentf list of my local emacs after a shut-down of the remote server. I would like for them to keep around. What exactly do I have to specify here and where do I have to do that?